# Retrieve some information about users and users' accounts using Banno digital toolkit

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We are currently integrating Banno consumer/Admin API into our system to retrieve information about users and users' accounts. However, we've encountered some difficulties in obtaining the following pieces of information.

1. Join Date: We require the date when an individual joined the financial institution (FI). Is there a specific property or endpoint that provides access to this information?
2. Direct Deposit: We need to know whether users utilize direct deposit services or not. Is there a property or flag within the API response that indicates whether direct deposit services are being used by the account holder?
3. Maturity Date: Some of the accounts have maturity dates associated with them. Could you please guide how to retrieve the maturity date information through the API?

I am sure there must be some way to obtain these as they are common requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> Join Date: We require the date when an individual joined the financial institution (FI). Is there a specific property or endpoint that provides access to this information?

This can be accessed from the [GET /a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/details](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/consumers/details/#/Retrieve%20user%20details/get_a_mobile_api_v0_institutions__institutionId__users__userId__details) endpoint. Specifically you are looking for the `userAdded` attribute.

> Direct Deposit: We need to know whether users utilize direct deposit services or not. Is there a property or flag within the API response that indicates whether direct deposit services are being used by the account holder?

There is not an endpoint that specifically indicates whether or not a user is utilizing direct deposit. You could piece together this information by inspecting transactions.

> Maturity Date: Some of the accounts have maturity dates associated with them. Could you please guide how to retrieve the maturity date information through the API?

I believe if this is available it would be found within the [GET /users/{userId}/accounts/{accountId}](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/accounts/details/#/Account%20Information/get_users__userId__accounts__accountId_) endpoint.